# Getting "Cannot find an overload for "AcquireTokenAsync" and the argument count: "2". At line:22 char:1" error

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get token using below script for databricks but I am getting this weird error. I tried it with different versions but still failing.

Cannot find an overload for "AcquireTokenAsync" and the argument count: "2".
At line:22 char:1

```
$AdminUserName = "XXXX"
$AdminPassword= "XXX"
$NativeClientAppId = "XXX"
$DatabricksResourceEnterpriseAppId = "XXX"
$TenantId = "XXX"


Write-Output("AdminUserName=$AdminUserName")
Write-Output("AdminPassword=$AdminPassword")
Write-Output("NativeClientAppId=$NativeClientAppId")
Write-Output("DatabricksAppId=$DatabricksResourceEnterpriseAppId")
Write-Output("TenantId=$TenantId")

# UserCredential Method
$adal = "D:\nuget\nuget\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.5.2.7\lib\net45\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll"
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($adal) | Out-Null
$creds = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserPasswordCredential" -ArgumentList $AdminUserName, $AdminPassword

$authString = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantID" 
$authContext = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext"-ArgumentList $authString
$authAction = $authContext.AcquireTokenAsync($NativeClientAppId, $creds)

$result = $authAction.Result

# If no result, it means there was a problem with authentication.  Need to throw the real error message instead of setting a null token.
if(!$result) {
    throw $authAction.Exception.InnerException
}
else {
    $aadToken = $result.AccessToken

    Write-Output ("$aadToken") 
}
```

What could be wrong here?

AzureAD     2.0.2.61

PSVersion   5.1.14393.3471

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserCredential latest

Comment: `AcquireTokenAsync()` has two overloads that use 2 arguments each: `AcquireTokenAsync(String, ClientCredential)` and `AcquireTokenAsync(String, ClientAssertion)`. Powershell doesn't know which one to use...

Comment: Thanks for reply, So what should I do in this case, what change I should make in my script?

Comment: Is your `$AdminPassword` a SecureString?

Comment: ye it is a secure string

Comment: Be careful with loading ADAL like that. The AzureAD module (and many other PowerShell modules) might load a different version of ADAL before your script, and if that happens, then your attempt to load ADAL 5.2.7 will not actually do anything. (You can check the version actually loaded with `$authContext.GetType().Assembly.FullName`.)

Comment: If you want to get azure ad access token with powershell, you can try to use [ADAL.PS](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ADAL.PS/3.19.4.2). For more details, please refer to https://github.com/kenakamu/Microsoft.ADAL.PowerShell/blob/master/Microsoft.ADAL.PowerShell/Microsoft.ADAL.PowerShell.psm1

Comment: this is not working at all. I used ADAL.PS but still getting same error. Cannot find an overload for "AcquireTokenAsync" and the argument count: "3".
At line:22 char:1